# Add an ID attribute to a dropped element with global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application with 5 canvas (with different ID and same class) that I can drag into a drop zone endless times (because i drop the draggable clone)

My question is:

I can add a dynamic ID to my dropped item with a global variable?

Example:

X = 1 (my global variable)
every time I go to do a drag and drop,and an item is put into the dropzone, will add an ID of this type:

ID = "nameX"

After setting ID the variable will increase (X++)

If i put 4 element i will have
"name1"
"name2"
ecc ecc

any advice about this??

Comment: So increment the id and build the string dynamically.

Comment: `function dynamicID() { return 'name' + x; x++; }` This is what you need?

Comment: I need the code script for adding an ID with the string + variable and i dont know how and where i decleare this global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is marked as jQuery, and I'm assuming the thing you are struggling with is retrieving that the ID of a given element.

Presumably your 'drop' logic is inside a jQuery callback function like this:

```
$("canvas").on("drop", function(event) {
   //this is the jQuery callback...
});
```

If so, you can get the ID of the element which called the event by using `$(this)`. Thusly;

```
$("canvas").on("drop", function(event) {
    var theCanvasID = $(this).attr("id"); // Get ID
    event.preventDefault();               // Stop browser from doing things about the drop
    event.stopPropagation();              // Don't let parent nodes do things either.
});
```

If you wanted to apply that as a global variable...

```
var X = false; // not set yet.
$("canvas").on("drop", function(event) {
    var theCanvasID = $(this).attr("id");
    X = theCanvasID;
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Please post a code sample next time. That was the vaguest question I have ever seen.

Comment: I know you are quite right, my question was too general, however, your response to me was inspiring and I have solved my problem (it was easier to believe what I did here)

Comment: +1 for remorse and also exploring your own alternative solutions based on what was posted. Welcome to StackOverflow :)